# How to use jquery with asp.net ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

Can you tell me examples for jquery with ajax?

Can I combine an UpdatePanel and jQuery behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing jQuery combined with ASP.NET Ajax for some time now, but never had to use the jQuery.NoConflict() method. It just works fine next to each other.

Matt Berseth has some articles about using them together (and many other great articles)

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/06/getting_jquery_goodness_into_a.html

Answer (score 1):

If you can call `jQuery.noConflict();` fast enough, you can stop it binding to `$`.

That means you have to refer to jQuery as `jQuery`. You can also use the return of `noConflict` to set it under another name:

```
$jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq('#div-id').whatever...
```

This doesn't help you neccessarily but it *should* stop there being conflicts.

Comment: If whoever gave me the downvote ever reads this, I'd appreciate knowing why... Not to whine too much, my answer is pretty near on what the top answer is... Posted earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't aware, [Microsoft are planning on supporting jQuery furthermore](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/28/jquery-and-microsoft.aspx), and they've allowed Intellisense to work with jQuery.

I'm not sure why you need to stop conflicts with jQuery though, they appear to work fine next to each other.  I develop both technologies at work with no problems.

So the answer is yes, but it depends on what you want to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may well be able to use jquery to perform local DHTML manipulation, but AFAIK, jQuery and ASP.NET (regular) don't make good bed-mates. However, jQuery and ASP.NET MVC work **very** tidily together. The viewstate etc in regular ASP.NET makes it a bit messy, and I'd stick with the MS offering for talking to the server with regular ASP.NET.